# React testing-library: File empty while testing file (pdf) upload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing file upload with react-testing-library, but log tells me that file is empty (however in browser it works)
I've read a lot of docs and bugs regarding this and what I've found: since test are running on node .js object File (since it extends Blob) miss some properties (all) and finally I see something like this

```
console.log
File {}
```

Here is my absctract code:

```
    const file = new File(['hello'], 'hello.pdf', {type: 'application/pdf'})
    const input = screen.getByTestId('attachment-input')
    await userEvent.upload(input, file)
```

I've tried to install blob polyfill and swap File with Blob but it starts to complain

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this

```
// Helper outside test body
function createFile(name: string, size: number, type: string) {
  const file = new File([], name, { type })
  Object.defineProperty(file, 'size', {
    get() {
      return size
    },
  })
  return file
}

const file = createFile('file1.pdf', 1.357 * 1024 * 1024, 'application/pdf')

const input = screen.getByTestId('attachment-input')
    await userEvent.upload(input, file)
```